# BlackBerry HttpConnection setting cookies

Tags: blackberry, cookies, set, httpconnection

this one has been killing me for a couple of days. I'm using a HttpConnection to access a REST server and need to set cookies on a GET method. I'm trying this using connection.setRequastMethod("Set-Cookie","cookie_data") and I just can't get it to work.

Comment: Don't you want setRequestProperty(), not setRequestMethod()? And I've never used this call, but I think the first argument may need to bee "Cookies" but I could be wrong.

Comment: You're right - typo - I am using setRequestProperty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cracked it - it was an issue with the way in which the server was behaving.

This server was of great use:

http://www.posttestserver.com/post.php